# Decodable forces super open class to implement the initializer

Tags: swift, decodable

I got this code:

```
open class A: Decodable {
    public init() {

    }
}

open class B: A {
    public override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    open required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        fatalError("init(from:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And the almighty Xcode 9.4.1 tells me I need to change `open` to `public` before the requiered keyword. After I change `open` to `public`, the compiler tells me I need to change it to `open`. I can't get it to work while both classes are `open`, without my super class A explicitly implementing the required initializer as seen in class B. Why?

Comment: Consider that `Codable` does not support inheritance by default.

Comment: @vadian Hmm, but if both classes are public, what does that matter to the initializer? class B knows it has a super class. I do not see why it not works with open classes.

Comment: Looks like a bug with the synthesised `init(from:)` in the superclass – it's fixed in Swift 4.2 (using Xcode 10 beta 6), using `public required init` in the subclass allows the code to compile.

Comment: Why the downvote? As above comment states it is a bug in the compiler, what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Decodable forces super open class to implement the initializer

If you don't inherit the required initializer the superclass has then you have to implement it yourself.

#### Required Initializers

> Write the required modifier before the definition of a class initializer to indicate that every subclass of the class must implement that initializer: <..>
>
> You must also write the required modifier before every subclass implementation of a required initializer, to indicate that the initializer requirement applies to further subclasses in the chain.
>
> You do not have to provide an explicit implementation of a required initializer if you can satisfy the requirement with an inherited initializer.

How you can avoid implementing it yourself:

## Initializer Inheritance

> Rule 1
>
> If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.

#### Sources

- [Initialization #Required Initializers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html)
- [Initialization #Automatic Initializer Inheritance](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID222)